# how to enable TLS 1.2 on android stock browser in Jelly bean

Tags: android, browser, tls1.2

I am trying to enable TLS 1.2 on android stock (default) browser on Android Jellybean. According to Android,  TLS 1.2 is supported but not enabled for Jelly bean.

How to enable TLS 1.2 on browser source code of android.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do this by replacing the SocketFactory like this:

```
Security.setProperty("ssl.SocketFactory.provider", "net.cogindo.ssl.TLSSocketFactory")
```

https://blog.dev-area.net/2015/08/13/android-4-1-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2/